# Views exposed filter by season from date field (date range group as month only?)

Tags: 8, datetime

How would I create an exposed filter by season (spring, summer, fall, winter) based on date fields? I figured the approach would be to create date range filter groups by MONTH only (no year), but I don't see a straightforward way of doing this.

Any tips or advice for getting a workable solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the season date ranges and name them by using the Grouping Exposed filter option.

You can find it in the regular Date filter, select `Grouped filters` instead of `Single filter` for the `Filter type to expose` option.

Set the operators to **Is between** and enter the dates for your seasons (you can see spring and summer in this screnshot):

[image: Views Date Grouped Exposed Filter]

Drupal will assume midnight if you ommit the time and only include the date. You can look up the exact astronomical times for the seasons if you like :)

Be careful not to exclude some results if you use the same date in separate grouped options but not the same time.

Comment: Thanks @prkos for the answer... but I'm looking to get the month range WITHOUT THE YEAR. Your example still includes the year 2021, so only Spring/Summer in 2021 will show. Do you have a possible solution for accomplishing this month range for any year?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. There are Contextual filters for creating monthly Summary results. I think you need a custom solution that would create a Contextual filter for the seasons, similar to how the month+year Contextual filter works.